# Concat blob data in Sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, blob

I have a table which contains image datatype in SQL SERVER 2008:

```
select ID,refID,blobcontent from dbo.Script where RefId=6000

ID   refID  blobcontent
456   45         0x50232323
987   45         0x54238798
852   45         0x52741985
```

I want to concat blobcontent in a row and insert into a new table group by refID. (the blob contents are long I just paste a sample).

example outpu:

```
ID        ConcatedBlob
456       0x5023232342387982741985
```

I know there is no direct concat() in sql server 2008 so I wrote the following query:

```
DECLARE @GroupDept VARBINARY(max)  
SELECT  @GroupDept = COALESCE(@GroupDept + ', ', '')+ blobcontent
FROM dbo.Script where RefId=6000
SELECT @GroupDept as 'total'
```

but get the error:

```
The data types varbinary(max) and varchar are incompatible in the add operator
```

Where is my mistake? any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: The desire output is the concatenation of the blobcontent column e.g. `0x50232323423879841985`. I want to store the concatenation in another table for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @Script AS TABLE
(
    Id int,
    RefId int,
    Blobcontent varbinary(max)
);

INSERT INTO @Script (Id, RefId, Blobcontent) VALUES
(456, 45, 0x50232323),
(987, 45, 0x54238798),
(852, 45, 0x52741985);
```

The query:

```
DECLARE @blobcontent varbinary(max)

SELECT @blobcontent = COALESCE(@blobcontent, 0x0) + blobcontent
FROM @Script
ORDER BY Id;

SELECT @blobcontent;
```

Comment: excuseme for latency. So how can I Insert the concated data into the new table? `@blobcontent` has the concatenated data just for one row I think. I have 1milion rows. may you please tell me the insert query too.